# Declarated a variable in WPF and i used it for another WPF wich C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a project with WPF when i introduce a UrlTxt in textbox with name txtCmdUrl
This is my code XAML station.xaml

```
<UserControl .....>


  <Grid x:Name="GridGlobal">
     <DockPanel Background="White" Margin="5" >
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 0 10 0">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                    **<TextBox x:Name="txtCommandeUrl"  Width="500" 
                       Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />**
                    <mui:ModernButton x:Name="btnSave" Content="{x:Static 
                       p:Resources.Link_Save_Link}" Click="BtnSave_Click" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding 
                      NextCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding 
                    NextEnabled}"/>                        
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And in my code behind i used my click button with this code

```
    private string txtUrlStation = "";

    //BtnSave_Click
    private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        try
        {
            txtUrlStation = txtCommandeUrl.Text;
            MessageBox.Show(txtSave);                                
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

I want to use my variable **txtCommandeUrl** for another file.xaml exemple station2.xaml in the code behind also.

Who can to help me in this small problem and Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this sort of thing. Which is best depends on exactly what you want to do.

Here are some you could use:

PRISM eventaggregator or Mvvmlight messenger to send the new value from one to the other as it changes. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26070.communicating-between-classes.aspx

Move your property to a static method on a static class which anything can then reference. Making it a "global".

Move your property to an instance class which you then pass round directly from one to another.

Move your property to an instance class which you then pass round indirectly using dependency injection from one to another.

Make it a public property and pass a reference from your first window/whatever to the next. This is more applicable to where the second is a child of the first because you're creating a dependency.

Comment: Then if i want to send my variable into to class.cs What is the code when i will used?

Comment: It depends which of the options you choose. There's a working sample for messenger. Dependency injection registers an instance of a class and when you resolve or get a class takes that type as a constructor parameter it provides the instance.  Passing by parameter hands over the parameter (often this ) to the class1 constructor when you new one up.